# Deferring google charts

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, deferred

I have this google charts code which works fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" async>

google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

var t1 = 'IndexTitle'
var t2 = 'IndicatorTitle'

google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){drawChart1(t1)});
google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){drawChart2(t2)});

function drawChart1(t){
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string','Date');
data.addColumn('number','Close');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
data.addRows([ChartIndexData...........]);
var options = {
    title: t,
    colors:['black'],  
    legend: {position: 'none'},
    chartArea:{left:60,top:20,width:'90%',height:'90%'}
   };
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart1_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}

function drawChart2(t){
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
data.addColumn('number', '');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
data.addRows([ChartIndicatorData...................]);
var options = {
    title: t,
    legend: {position: 'none'},
    chartArea:{left:60,top:20,width:'90%',height:'60%'}
  };
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart2_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}<%
</script>
```

The problem is when I test the page on Google PageSpeed insite the score is 49/100 because of the script above:

```
Remove render-blocking 
JavaScript:https://www.google.com/jsapi
https://www.google.com/…ile=visualization&v=1&packages=corechart
https://www.google.com/…at+en,default+en,ui+en,corechart+en.I.js

Optimize CSS Delivery of the following:
https://www.google.com/…bdd6ab2d343a51d49841bf93d022fb/ui+en.css
https://ajax.googleapis.com/…static/modules/gviz/1.0/core/tooltip.css
```

As I understand I have to load javascript Asynchronous or defer the loading.

How do I fix it.

Comment: Tried

 window.onload = function () { 
   google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart"], callback: drawCharts});
   
   var t1 = 'IndexTitle'
   var t2 = 'IndicatorTitle'
 
   function drawCharts() {
     drawChart1(t1);
     drawChart2(t2);
   }
 }

and it worked.Also, now I was able to change

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
 
to

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi" async></script>

Answer (score 1):

Tried

```
window.onload = function () { 
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart"], callback: drawCharts});

  var t1 = 'IndexTitle'
  var t2 = 'IndicatorTitle'

  function drawCharts() {
    drawChart1(t1);
    drawChart2(t2);
  }
}
```

and it worked. Also, now I was able to change

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi" async></script>
```

which pushed the Google PageInsite score from 49 to 82. Still Google pageInsight shows

```
Optimize CSS Delivery of the following:
https://www.google.com/…bdd6ab2d343a51d49841bf93d022fb/ui+en.css
https://ajax.googleapis.com/…static/modules/gviz/1.0/core/tooltip.css
```

as I understand these CSS are loaded when

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart"], callback: drawCharts});
```

is called. How do I optimize that?